# angular-devise Auth not working until page refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise

I'm using angular-devise and I have the following service that checks whether the user is logged or not

```
        isAuthenticated: function ($state, Auth) {

            Auth.currentUser().then(function (){
                console.log("user is logged");
            }, function(error) {
                $state.go('home',{});
                console.log("user is not logged");
            })
```

The problem is when I log the user on the server side it keeps returning that he's not logged in until I refresh the page. Then, after the refersh, it says that the user is logged as expected.

What am I missing here? Thank you!

Comment: How are you maintaining the user session ?

Comment: With Devise gem on Rails

Comment: Devise gem is at the backend side. How do you maintain the session at the front end ? Do you save any details in the cookies etc ? Or just after refreshing the page you need to fetch the current user again ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Rails on the backend and Angular on the frontend. On the frontend I'm also using this angular-devise service which is supposed to maintain the session on cookies. Following the documentation https://github.com/cloudspace/angular_devise the isAuthenticated service for example works very well when I log the user on the client-side (using Auth.login). But when I log him on the server side, all the methods work only after I refresh the page... maybe I should do something on the backend to update the clients cookies...